# TexLive: extra fonts for XeTeX and LuaTeX installed locally

Tags: fonts, xetex, luatex, texlive

I have a problem with XeTeX and extra fonts installed with TexLive 2020, which are required for XeTex and LuaTeX. I work on Ubuntu 2020.

The file name I am referring to is `texlive-fontconfig.conf`. According to [The TeX Live Guide—2020](https://www.tug.org/texlive/doc/texlive-en/texlive-en.html#x1-140003) or specifically the section *3.4.4 System font conﬁguration for XeTeX and LuaTeX*, I should copy the file to `/etc/fonts/config.d/` (system-wide) or to `~/.fonts.conf` (user-wide) and rename it as `09-texlive.conf`. Then I should run `sudo fc-cache -fs` or `fc-cache -f`, respectively.

The syste-wide approach works Okey. I can compile a test file `opentype-info.tex` using XeTeX and produce a pdf file.

When I try to cache the same fonts just for a user, XeTeX reports that fonts are not loadable. I tried to re-open a terminal and even restarted the system but XeTeX still complains about missing fonts when I compile the same test file. Is there anything else I should do to make those fonts visible for XeTeX (and possibly LuaTeX)?

Comment: Please specify exactly which TeXLive you have installed. As the Ubuntu provided one and the TUG provided one (upstream) might not behave the same.

Comment: Just use LuaTeX and then there is no need to install `texlive-fontconfig.conf` in the first place.

Comment: `tlmgr --version` retutns: `tlmgr revision 57119 (2020-12-13 00:40:00 +0100)`, `tlmgr using installation: [/path/to/]texlive/2020`, and `TeX Live (https://tug.org/texlive) version 2020`

Comment: Instead of `~/.fonts.conf` you could try the the more modern location `~/.config/fontconfig/conf.d`.

Comment: I edited my question. It's supposed to be `~/.fonts.conf`; it was a typo. I have been following the user guide on installation TexLive, which currently states to copy a file to `~/.fonts.conf`. They should update it! I also copied the fontconfig file to the location you suggested and it's working. So, many thanks for help.

Comment: [font.conf](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hirsute/man5/fonts-conf.5.html) on Ubuntu Manual specifies that location among the other folders. I did not realise `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME` actually refers to `~/.config/`. I am still new but a little bit wiser :)